# Compress a camera image and save it in Sqlite in android

Tags: android

i need to save a camera image from sd card to sqlite in android. The problem i am facing is out of memory exception. How i can compress this image and sav it in sqlite. The image format is jpeg
thanks in advance
jibysthomas

Comment: Its not a good idea to save binary data in sqlite, I would recommend saving the file path in the database.

Comment: We have made a comparison of both approach: I definitely agree with Alan… So, save the picture somewhere and store the uri in the db.

Comment: The images need to be private for the application so i have to done so

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the best way to save storage space using SQLite and I am still looking for it, but here we go.

You can select the source of your image, such as gallery or camera and below is the code.

```
private void selectProductImage() {
        final CharSequence[] itens = {"Use Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertDialog);
        builder.setItems(itens, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (itens[which].equals("Use Camera")) {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Use Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    } else {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }

                } else if (itens[which].equals("Gallery")) {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO);

                } else if (itens[which].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Maybe you need permission to use the camera

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
```

Here is how to handle the image from the source you selected.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"),96, 96, true);
        mProductImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        isPriviteImage = true;
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //mProductImage.setImageURI(data.getData());

        // INSERT IMAGE INTO SQLite
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream),96, 96, true);
            mProductImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            isPriviteImage = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can notice in my example, there is no place to save the image case you selected **camera** and I placed the image on an `ImageView` variable named **mProductImage**.

From now, you can use a **Button** to save the image in your SQLite Database. Here is the function you can use for it.

```
private void saveImage() {

    productTablePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/YourAditionalPath/";

    ProductDatabaseHelper productDatabaseHelper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext(), "dbname.db", productTablePath);
    productListTable = productDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    productRepository = new ProductRepository(productListTable);

    try {

        if (isPriviteImage) {
            productRepository.addProduct(imageViewToByte(mProductImage));
            isPriviteImage = false;

        } else {
            productRepository.addProduct(null);

        }

        mProductImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.shopping_cart_black_48dp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Where `imageViewToByte` functon is:

```
private byte[] imageViewToByte(CircleImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

Now you need to implement the **SQLiteOpenHelper**. You need to create a new class for this. The java file name I used for this was **ProductDatabaseHelper.java**.

```
public class ProductDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static int dbVersion = 1;

    public ProductDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, String storageDirectory) {
        super(context, storageDirectory+name, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        sql.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCTLIST (");

        sql.append("        IMAGE        BLOB,");


        db.execSQL(sql.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Now you need to implement your CRUD (Create new item, Read, Update and Delete).

```
public class ProductRepository {

    SQLiteDatabase instance;

    public ProductRepository(SQLiteDatabase instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void addProduct(byte[] image){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("IMAGE",image);

        instance.insertOrThrow("PRODUCTLIST",null, contentValues);
    }


}
```

It is important to mention that the compression of the image was made in the `onActivityResult()` for both source image (camera and gallery).

with the command:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(capturedImage, width, height, true);
```

Besides that, here is a link where we can read a little bit about compression.

https://androidwave.com/capture-image-from-camera-gallery/

If you have a better way to compress images to save in SQLite Database, please post your code here!